# CSS Background Not Showing

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Hey guy's I've been trying out something different with my CSS backgrounds in order to make a header line. I want to have it set up so the line is made up of 5 equally sized portions with each portion being a different color. Here is an example [image] 
I have the code set up but I can't get the background to show up properly I have my code down below. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="div-line">
    <div class="blockOne"></div>
    <div class="blockTwo"></div>
    <div class="blockThree"></div>
    <div class="blockFour"></div>
    <div class="blockFive"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #div-line {
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}

.blockOne {
    width:20%;
    background-image:url(../images/orangeBlock.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockTwo {
    width:20%;
    background-image:url(../images/blueBlock.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockThree {
    width:20%;
    background-image:url(../images/darkOrangeBlock.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockFour {
    width:20%;
    background-image:url(../images/orangeBlock.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockFive {
    width:20%;
    background-image:url(../images/BlueBlock.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use borders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to float the `DIV` elements and add height.
[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mYn7J/)

Added a generic CSS class `block` in HTML:

```
<div id="div-line">
    <div class="block blockOne"></div>
    <div class="block blockTwo"></div>
    <div class="block blockThree"></div>
    <div class="block blockFour"></div>
    <div class="block blockFive"></div>
</div>
```

and tweaked CSS:

```
    #div-line {
       width:100%;
       height:5px;
    }

    .block {
      height:100%;
      float:left;
      width:20%;  
    }

    .blockOne {
       background-color:red;   
    }

    .blockTwo {
        background-color:black; 
    }

    .blockThree {
        background-color:red; 
    }

    .blockFour {
            background-color:black; 
    }

    .blockFive {
           background-color:red; 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using `background` for color. And the reason why your divs are not showing up is because you need to give them a height and also you need to float them to the left.

```
#div-line div {
    float:left;    
    }

#div-line {
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
   }

.blockOne {
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:#00FFFF;
    }

.blockTwo {
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:#FFA500;
    }

.blockThree {
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:#00FFFF;
    }

.blockFour {
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:#FFA500;
    }

.blockFive {
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:#00FFFF;
    }
```

Working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mmetsalu/X2JE6/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use background images where you can use background-color ?

You can offload the server atleast if you use background color.

```
.blockN {
 width: 20%;
 background-color: #0094ff; // or your color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
.blockOne {
width:20%;
background-image:url(images/orangeBlock.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockTwo {
width:20%;
background-image:url(images/blueBlock.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockThree {
width:20%;
background-image:url(images/darkOrangeBlock.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockFour {
width:20%;
background-image:url(images/orangeBlock.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockFive {
width:20%;
background-image:url(images/BlueBlock.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

**OR**

```
.blockOne {
width:20%;
background-image:url(./images/orangeBlock.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockTwo {
width:20%;
background-image:url(./images/blueBlock.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockThree {
width:20%;
background-image:url(./images/darkOrangeBlock.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockFour {
width:20%;
background-image:url(./images/orangeBlock.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.blockFive {
width:20%;
background-image:url(./images/BlueBlock.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

The thing you are trying to do ie, `background-image:url(images/orangeBlock.png)` is used in linux.